# ¿Cómo redireccionar peticiones que solicitan imágenes con apache?

Tags: apache

Tengo un problema, no tengo muy claro como se utiliza apache, y necesito hacer lo siguiente. Tengo que redireccionar imágenes que se llamen `nombre_descripcion_$IDnumerico.JPG` a su nombre real `IDnumerico.jpg` y no tengo ni idea de cómo solucionarlo.

He probado con

```
RewriteRule "(.(1-9).(jpg|jpeg))$" "http://directorio/imagenes/" [P,NC]
```

No tengo ni idea de utilizar esta herramienta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, y faltan definiciones; pero si se trata de las imagenes de un directorio, puedes agregar un `.htaccess` (si la configuración de Apache lo permite) al directorio con este contenido:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*_([0-9]+)\.(jpg|jpeg)$ $1.$2 [L,NC]
```

Esta es una regla de reemplazo, con expresiones regulares:

```
  .*       => cualquier cosa  
  _        => (literal) guion bajo
  ()       => agrupa un match
  [0-9]+   => cualquier digito, 1 o más veces
  \.       =>  punto (literal)
  jpg|jpeg => cualquiera de las extensiones (puedes agregar mas)
```

Esto se reemplaza a  "$1.$2" que corresponde al contenido de los dos grupos matcheados (entre paréntesis). El flag NC (No Case) indica que el matching no distingue mayúsculas vs minúsculas.

(Lo anterior supone que quieres respetar la extensión que te pasan. Si quieres forzar a "`jpg`" siempre, cambia "`$2`" por "`jpg`".)

Answer (score 0):

La Apache Software Foundation no recomienda, por motivos de seguridad y rendimiento, el uso de archivos `.htaccess`. Concretamente, puedes leer esta información en la documentación oficial: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

> "For security and performance reasons, do not set  AllowOverride to anything other than None in your   block. Instead, find (or create) the  block that refers to the directory where you're actually planning to place a .htaccess file."

Mi recomendación es que configures la directiva `AllowOverride` a `None` como propone la Apache Software Foundation e incorpores la configuración proporcionada por @leonbloy (que no deja de ser correcta), dentro del bloque `Directory` correspondiente en lugar de crear un archivo `.htaccess` solo para ello.

Una vez echo esto, debes reiniciar el servidor Apache para que los cambios surtan efecto.

Comment: Sé que OP no menciona nada sobre eso pero, ¿podría hacerse esto en un servidor compartido?